# ActiveMQ AjaxServlet not working on Weblogic

Tags: java, ajax, weblogic, activemq-classic

I'm trying to run ActiveMQ AjaxServlet with embedded broker inside Weblogic. I'm using the web.xml and maven dependencies from example, which is here: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/activemq/trunk/activemq-web-demo/src/main/webapp/
After accessing the page(or trying to connect with a client), I get this exception thrown at the server:

```
Servlet failed with Exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: !(Jetty || Servlet 3.0 || ContinuationFilter)
at org.eclipse.jetty.continuation.ContinuationSupport.getContinuation(ContinuationSupport.java:150)
at org.apache.activemq.web.MessageListenerServlet.doMessages(MessageListenerServlet.java:309)
at org.apache.activemq.web.MessageListenerServlet.doGet(MessageListenerServlet.java:246)
at org.apache.activemq.web.AjaxServlet.doGet(AjaxServlet.java:47)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at org.apache.activemq.web.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:45)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

> 

Do I need to add Jetty to Weblogic? Is that possible? Is that wise?

Weblogic version is 10.3.6. Can switching to Weblogic 12 solve the problem(it has Servlet 3.0)

Here's web.xml:

```
    <!--ACTIVE MQ-->
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.activemq.brokerURL</param-name>
    <param-value>vm://localhost</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.activemq.embeddedBroker</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AjaxServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.activemq.web.AjaxServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MessageServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.activemq.web.MessageServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>QueueBrowseServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.activemq.web.QueueBrowseServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AjaxServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/amq/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>QueueBrowseServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/queueBrowse/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MessageServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/message/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here are dependencies of ActiveMQ servlet:

```
        <!--ActiveMQ-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-web</artifactId>
        <version>${version.activeMQ}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activeio-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-jaas</artifactId>
        <version>${version.activeMQ}</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${version.slf4j}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-jaas</artifactId>
        <version>${version.activeMQ}</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weblogic 10.X doesn't support Servlet 3.0. 
Switching to Weblogic 12 solved the problem.